# Unable to understand how smart contracts work

Tags: solidity, ethereum-classic

I'm reading several articles about privacy in ethereum smart contracts but still I don't understand how everything in the smart contract is visible to anyone?

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

On a public blockchain, all the transactions between accounts (externally controlled and smart contract) are public. You can browse each transaction of each block using tools such as [EtherScan](https://etherscan.io).

For example, on the picture below, you can see every data for a transaction to a smart contract (write operation) :

- Transaction Hash
- Block No
- Timestamp
- From account
- To account
- Value
- Gas
- **Input data : This is the data passed to the smart contract which are totally public**

[image]

Moreover, you can call read only (`constant`) operations for a smart contract if you have the [ABI](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Ethereum-Contract-ABI) and the contract address.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint storedData;

    function set(uint x) public {
        storedData = x;
    }

    function get() public constant returns (uint) {
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

Here anybody can call `get()` to retrieve the value of storedData

Comment: In your example contract, what could be the input data? Although it is public, it's not in readable format...

Comment: It's not a readable format but someone who knows how it works can decrypt it quite easily. It's basically hexadecimal